# Looking for guidance to resolve a difference of opinion - play button on image that is not clickable

Tags: video, guidance

We have an image used as a cover photo for a module that contains videos. The cover photo is an image of a video with a play button in the middle. But it isn't a video and can't be clicked. You actually have to click into lessons in the module before you get to a real video.

I'm looking for UX "wisdom" on this topic. Is it reasonable to do this? If not, why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

#### Consider that users come to your site with expectations from all the other sites they visit.

An extremely common interaction when a user clicks a 'Play' icon, is that a video will begin playing. It's **interaction**, not navigation to a collection of items.

A good heuristic here is **[Jakob's Law](https://www.nngroup.com/videos/jakobs-law-internet-ux/)**

> Users spend most of their time on other sites. This means that users prefer your site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know. Design for patterns for which users are accustomed.

Rather than have users tricked into thinking they're getting a video, you could overlay a clearly visible button that could say <kbd>View lessons ></kbd>  or something equivalent.

Then the play button is reserved for content that plays directly.

Comment: Agreed. Even if the image navigated me to a page where I could watch that video, it would still break my expectations.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the concept 'affordance' is relevant. E.g. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance.

The play button, [ ▶︎ ], is a very strong affordance to click.

Remove me the click-to-play 'affordance' from the image. For example, in the way that "@Mike M" suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend removing the image of a button from your course cover since it's a common affordance and everyone will be prompted to select it. You can look at your course project and add a cover illustration that showcases and reflects what's inside the course, thus users will be more motivated to check the videos inside.